# Finding Strong and Weak Clusters and their membership in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I should find weak clusters and membership of the nodes in the clusters, and strong clusters and membership of the nodes in the clusters.

My code :

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(8, 15/100)
is.connected(g, mode=("strong"))
clusters(g, mode="strong")
no.clusters(g, mode="strong")
cluster.distribution(g, cumulative = FALSE, mul.size = FALSE)
```

As solution I got this :

```
> library(igraph)
> g <- erdos.renyi.game(8, 15/100)
> is.connected(g, mode=("strong"))
[1] FALSE
> clusters(g, mode="strong")
$membership
[1] 1 2 1 1 3 1 4 1

$csize
[1] 5 1 1 1

$no
[1] 4

> no.clusters(g, mode="strong")
[1] 4
> cluster.distribution(g, cumulative = FALSE, mul.size = FALSE)
[1] 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
```

But I didnt get which are my strong clusters, and i how can i plot my strong clusters in different color?
Is there any good tutorial for R studio , coz there are no many sources for R studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clusters are in the `membership` part of `clusters(g, mode="strong")`

```
set.seed(247)
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(8, 15/100)
```

They are in the order of your nodes in the graph e.g.

```
V(g) # the nodes in your graph are 1-8
#Vertex sequence:
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

# the respective cluster for nodes 1-8 are:
clusters(g, mode="strong")$membership
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 4 5 2
```

To colour these in your plot do something like:

```
strongclusters <- clusters(g, mode="strong")$membership
plot(g, vertex.color = strongclusters)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :), Does it mean that in this seed, strong clusters are with membership 3, 4 or 5? and is there any function which shows number of strong clusters?

Comment: Number of (strong) clusters is in your output above, under `$no`. Or, the same is in the output of `no.clusters`. What did you think that function was doing?

Comment: @Gabor Csardi, i was thinking about showing it somethere on the plotted graph, like picture of graph below, number of strong clusters and their membership, sorry that my question was not understandable.

Comment: You mean, you wanted to put the number 4 on the plot? Then you can use either the `title()` or the more general `text()` command.